# SQL exception: no value specified for parameter

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting a SQL exception "no value for parameter 3", I print all the value on the console. Why does it throw an exception?

```
String update="select * from net_cr_dr where (soc_code=? and tdate >=?) and tdate <=?";
ResultSet rsselect=null;
System.out.println(startdate11)
System.out.println(enddate)
System.out.println(milkcode)
System.out.println("phase8b")
PreparedStatement  selnet= conn.prepareStatement(update)

selnet.setDate(3,startdate11)
selnet.setDate(2,enddate)
selnet.setInt(1,milkcode)
rsselect = selnet.executeQuery();
```

Comment: may be try to order setters of params?

Comment: i try that but it didn't work

Comment: are you sure startdate11 is a Date object?

Comment: If startdate11  is not a Date object then setDate would not compile. The original posted code was not compilable till I fixed it; I suspect the code that fails for op does not have `selnet.setDate(3,...)` at all.

Comment: What are the types of variable startdate11, enddate and milkcode?

Comment: And does it work if you try: selnet.setDate(3,new Date());
selnet.setDate(2,new Date());
selnet.setInt(1,1);  :-)? And I wonder how do you manage to run this code with so few semicolons...

Comment: is startdate11 and enddate a object of java.util.Date or java.sql.Date ?

Comment: Code that you posted won't even compile. Can you post whole class and output?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you may try setTimestamp as well instead of setDate (although I don't think this is the root cause)

Comment: If you are not sure about the answer . Do not put assumptions here put that on comments..